# Play several m3u8 in a row

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, m3u8, hls.js

I have multiple links to m3u8 files and would like to play them in a row one after another in a single player instance.

I'm currently using [hls.js](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js) but I'll happily change to another player.

Comment: Here is an example m3u8 link https://test-streams.mux.dev/x36xhzz/url_6/193039199_mp4_h264_aac_hq_7.m3u8

Comment: It seems like what I'm looking for is a "playlist of m3u8 playlists".

Comment: Also wasn't able to download the m3u8 files and concatenate them into one single m3u8 file.